# What is the name of "group over 2 sets"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I remember finding a very useful algebraic structure that I loosely call "group over 2 sets" because I can't remember its real name or find it. I looked at all the algebraic structures on Wikipedia, but it wasn't mentioned there even though I remember it having its own page.

Anyway, I'll define the algebraic structure more formally:

It has 2 sets $P$ and $D$, where $D$ is a group over addition, 2 operations $+ : P \times D \rightarrow P$ and $- : P \times P \rightarrow D$ and few laws:

$$
x + (y - x) = y
\\
(y - x) + (x - y) = 0
\\
(x - x) = 0
\\
x + 0 = x
$$

And possibly some more laws. I'm not sure I remember them all.

I remember the structure being used for describing the relation between e.g. points and vectors (the set of points being P and vectors being D) or times = P and timedifferences = D.

Does anyone know how this algebraic structure is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [torsor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_homogeneous_space): more precisely, it is the structure of a (right) $D$-torsor on the set $P$.  There are various ways to axiomatize such a structure, but one simple way is to say that $D$ is a group which acts on the set $P$ (on the right) and for any $a,b\in P$, there is a unique $d\in D$ such that $ad=b$.  In your notation, $+$ is the group action and $-$ is the map taking $(b,a)$ to $d$.  (Of course, your additive notation is normally used only when the group $D$ is abelian.)

In the special case that $D$ is not just a group but a vector space, a $D$-torsor is also called an affine space, as rschwieb mentioned.

Comment: I had followed the link to "principal homogenous space" to find out what it was, and discovered this along the way too. I've only just heard of it, so I don't know what to say about the more general one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about axioms for an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space). That's what it reminds me of, anyway.

The axioms describe, essentially, the action of an abelian group on a set.